# For Statement with Two Conditions

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I tried to combine all the codes together to make it look at one record at a time. The second part of the codes are looking at all the rows in a loop. Ideally, I would like to look at customer A's record and hide the row#66 or row#64. After that the code is supposed to start over from the top to look at Customer B,C,D... Thanks to the people who answered my questions about for loop. Thank you

```
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    .Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    .Activate
    For Each c In .Range("E27,E32,E35,L36,L37,E39,E40,E41,E42,E43,E44,E45,E46,E49,E50,E51")
        If c.Value = 0 Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    
   
End With



With Worksheets("Template")
    If .Range("E26").Value = 0 Or .Range("E27") = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Template").Rows("69").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Worksheets("Template").Rows("69").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
    If .Range("E32").Value = 0 Then
    Worksheets("Template").Rows("70").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
    Worksheets("Template").Rows("70").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End With
```

---

```
Dim r As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data File")
    For Each r In ws2.Range("CU3:CU5")
    If r.Value = "RSU" And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: There are multiple rows in CU3:CV5 - are they all hiding/showing the same rows?  `If r.Value = "RSU" And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" Then` would work if you only loop over the cells in col CU

Comment: Thank you for your comments. What if I want to loop over the cells in both col CU and CV? I don't want to hide the row if CV value is "N".

Comment: I posted all my codes here . I have a new challenge because the for loop will look at all records in a loop instead of looking at one row at a time. I want the code to start over from the beginning after it hides row 64 or row 66

Comment: I think I head to the wrong direction. I could have modify the second section of the codes to make it work. I don't really need a for loop in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, but I'm still confused how you account for multiple rows in the range you're looping over - you will be left with whatever the match works out as from the last row in that range.

```vb
Dim rw As Range, matched As Boolean
For Each rw In ws2.Range("CU3:CV5").Rows  'loop over rows in range
    'row matches conditions?
    matched = rw.Cells(1).Value = "RSU" And rw.Cells(2).Value = "Y"
    With Worksheets("Template")
        .Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = Not matched
        .Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = matched
    End With
Next rw
```

EDIT: after your update

```vb
Dim c As Range, ws As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")

ws.Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
For Each c In ws.Range("E27,E32,E35,L36,L37,E39,E40,E41,E42,E43,E44,E45,E46,E49,E50,E51").Cells
    If c.Value = 0 Then c.EntireRow.Hidden = c.Value = 0
Next
    
ws.Rows(69).EntireRow.Hidden = ws.Range("E26").Value = 0 Or ws.Range("E27") = 0
ws.Rows(70).EntireRow.Hidden = ws.Range("E32").Value = 0
```

Comment: I posted all my codes. I have a new challenge because the for loop will look at all records in a loop instead of looking at one row at a time. I want the code to start over from the beginning after it hides row 64 or row 66

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for. It's same as @Tim's comment. You don't have to keep `Two Conditions` in `For` clause.

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In ws2.Range("CU3:CU5")
    If r.Value = "RSU" And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y" Then
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Worksheets("Template").Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next r
```

The code could be simplified as below.

```
    Dim r As Range, bFlag As Boolean
    For Each r In ws2.Range("CU3:CU5")
        bFlag = (r.Value = "RSU" And r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Y")
        With Worksheets("Template")
            .Rows(66).EntireRow.Hidden = Not bFlag
            .Rows(64).EntireRow.Hidden = bFlag
        End With
    Next r
```

Comment: Thank you very much for both of your feedback. I would need to post another question to show you everything. I should have post my codes all at once.